# Can we convert an EXE into a program which can be Auto-Installed without any Clicks or Commands just after download, or may be on System Restart

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a developed a Windows Utility on VS & Asp.Net which is moreover a System Performance Enhancer. It installs normally as other Windows Desktop Software do.

Can we compile an EXE or MSI of that utility which Auto-Installs on a User's System. Let's suppose, the file gets downloaded on a computer. It sits safe in the downloads folder till the time the user restarts the system. OR, maybe some better option.

Please help me.

Comment: -1 for language tag spam. What does this question have to do with programming in Java? Close vote for an over-broad question. Please go through the [tour] and the [help] sections to see how this site works.

Comment: the desired behavior has to be considered a major security risk ...

Answer (score 5):

Auto install, etc.. ? If this was possible, viruses would rule the pc world. There is UAC in windows + antivir in browser. No workaround for this without user agreement ;)